# How to solve an under determined system for a ratio of variables?

Tags: equation-solving, boundary-conditions

I have two equations in 3 variables `a2`, `b1`, `b2`:

```
a2 p (-na1 + p) + b1 (-nb1^2 + p^2) + b2 (-nb1^2 + p^2) == 0
2 (b1 + b2) mu nb1 p + a2 (2 mu p^2 + lambda (na1^2 + p^2)) == 0
```

Is there a single function I can use to solve for the ratios b2/b1 and a2/b1? If not, what is the best approach?

Comment: Best approach? set $b_1=1$ and solve for $a_2,b_2$...

Comment: You may use `Reduce[{equations}, {a2,b1,b2}]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce new variables d1 = a2/b1 and d2 = b2/b1.

```
eqs2 = eqs /. a2 -> b1 d1 /. b2 -> b1 d2;

red1 = Reduce[eqs2, {d1, d2}]

TraditionalForm[(red1 // ToRadicals) //. 
    Or -> Composition[(Column[#, Right, 
  Background -> {{White, LightGray}}, Frame -> All] &), List]]
```

[image]

This did not restrict to reals, you see the complex roots.
Otherwise it would be a very large expresssion.

And here a solution that is always true independent of other parameters:

```
sol1 = Solve[eqs2, {d1, d2}]

{*   {{d1 -> 0, d2 -> -1}}   *}
```